# Shorthand for conditionally creating an array out of an optional value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that optionally accepts an array. I have other variables that may be `undefined`, but if they are defined I would like to create an array from it:

```js
function test(array?: string[]) {
    console.log(array);
}

let value: string | undefined;
value = 'abc';

const temp = value ? [value] : undefined; // Shorthand?
test(temp)
```

Is there a shorthand way of creating the `temp` variable with an an array of `strings` or pass `undefined`? I tried to do the following but didn't achieve it:

```
// If value is 1, true, or 'some string' it will take that value not the array
const temp = value && [value];

// Passes back an empty array if value is undefined
const temp = [value].filter(Boolean),
```

Comment: The ternary *is* the shorthand, and will be parsed correctly by typescript. Why are you trying to tangle what is very straightforward logic? (none of the short circuits or coallescing operators will return undefined on failure)

Comment: What’s wrong with your first code? It’s readable to me

Comment: I have a lot of these in a code base and was hoping to avoid all the `undefined` noise

Comment: write a helper function

Comment: I might have to fallback on that but was hoping if there was something native in the language

Comment: There is, it's called a ternary. Your last option is far more inefficient than typing undefined since it will always create an array, then iterate it, and then not return the correct type on failure any way.

Comment: The main issue with `value && [value]` is that an empty string is considered a falsy value. Assuming `value` is of type `string | undefined` the return type of `value && [value]` is `undefined | string | string[]`, because if an empty string is passed then the `&&` is short-circuited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was pointed out in the comments, just create a helper function for this:

```
const arrOrUndef = <T,>(val: T | undefined): T[] | undefined => val !== undefined ? [val] : undefined;
```

Then just use:

```
let value: string | undefined = 'abc';
test(arrOrUndef(value))
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQeQQVTAEwKYDMYC8MAPACoA0AfABQBucANgFwykwA+MArlngJZhsmAJQtSAbQC6Hbr1wChhSjHoMYAQgJEeOeYMwwA-DHGrpLHf30BuAFC3QkEA2wA6BiADm1RCnRziaAQBTxoAIgAJbAYPMOFhB3AIZzcPb19UDF1iADkuAFsAI2wEGgAWACZ4xKcXdy8fJEyAsC4YmlaY6sdkurTGvyy8XILi0uoABnigA)

Also, thanks to [pilchard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13762301/pilchard) in the comments for noting that it is better to use a generic, rather than just the `string` type in your question or the `any` type. Also, [JDB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211627/jdb) for noting you must use `!== undefined`, rather than simply checking for a falsy value (as the original question does).

Comment: @pilchard Good point, I'll change my answer to use a generic.

Comment: Good idea about the generics. How about ending up with something like this: `value?.toArray()`? is it possible to attach a function like this to all undefinable types or not a good idea?

Comment: @TruMan1 I'd think that adding that method to every type would be a bad idea (I'm thinking [SmooshGate](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/smooshgate/)). Probably better to just use a function.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for something like the opposite of the [nullish coalescing operator (`??`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing): instead of evaluating the second part if the first expression is `undefined`, you want it to evaluate the second part if the first is *not* `undefined`.

As of the date of this post, **there is no operator ("shorthand") like that**. Your best bet is a helper function or a ternary operator (as you're already aware).

Here's an example that also works with falsish values like `0`:

```js
const makeArray = <T>(value: T|undefined): T[]|undefined =>
    value === undefined ? undefined : [value];

makeArray(undefined); // undefined
makeArray(null); // [null]
makeArray("foo"); // ["foo"]
makeArray(false); // [false]
makeArray(0); // [0]
```